# How can an EL-Expression be used to set emptyMessage on dataTable (PF)?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I'm trying to set the emptyMessage-Attribute of a dataTable whereas I would like to access values of a backing bean - something like (which is of course not evaluating properly):

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{data.employeeHasNoAbsences ? '#{ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test')}' :  #{ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test2')}}"
```

Without accessing a backing bean it would be:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{data.employeeHasNoAbsences ? 'No' : 'Yes'}"
```

Which works fine.

Is the first thing somehow  possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting EL expressions is illegal syntax. You should see the `#{}` as one big space where variables/strings can interact with each other.

You ultimately want this evaluation:

```
data.employeeHasNoAbsences ? ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test') : ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test2')
```

Now, just put **exactly** that evaluation inside `#{}`:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{data.employeeHasNoAbsences ? ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test') : ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test2')}">
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I hope that you're not reinventing the builtin `ResourceBundle` facility this way.

Comment: Thanks BalusC - I hoped for your answer ;). I tried your suggestion in the code but eclipse murred that this would be a wrong el expression. I was not confident enough to try it out myself - sorry for that one. Still learning.

Unrelated: No. Although I tend to reinventing - we are using a BPMS (Business Process Management Suite) which comes with it's own CMS and a lot more stuff. It is an eclipse plugin (Xpert.ivy).

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{data.employeeHasNoAbsences ? ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test') : ivy.cms.co('/Labels/Test2')}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BalusC pointed out the same thing. [see above]